# xslt 2.0 program freezing because of complex computations

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have two same name templates with different functionalities in xslt. Both templates involve two complex computations. The objective of template is to compute if some parameters in each table are available in other tables. The parameters are not readily available in the table and need to be computed. Hence i have used two templates as follows

```
<xsl:template match="table1" mode="main">
  <xsl:variable name="var1">
    <!--complex computations for variable here-->
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="var2">
    <!--complex computations for variable here-->
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//table1" mode="intermediate">
    <xsl:with-param name="var1_main" select="$var1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="var2_main" select="$var2"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table1" mode="intermediate">
  <xsl:param name="var1_main"/>
  <xsl:param name="var2_main"/>
  <xsl:variable name="var1">
    <!--complex computations for variable here. Same computation as for mode      main template-->
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="var3"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="$var3">
   <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem faced is when template table1 mode=intermediate is called, the saxon processor is taking too long to execute the program. Infact i have to close the processor by pressing ctrl+c in command prompt to continue with my work. Is there any method to compute such computation effectively without freezing the xslt processor.

The following is additional information required for the question.
The major computations involved are as follows:

Computation1 : From table1 we obtain the concerned table2_ID(for current table1 node) and from the table2_ID of table1 we obtain the table3_ID's (multiple ids) from where we obtain the values for `<table1/>`. So as per problem each `<table1/>` can have many `<Values>`. the computation of is not straightforward as shown in the dummy example. There is a computation scheme for `<values>` which i cannot disclose.

Computation2 : in `<tables1>` after obtaining all  for each `<table1>` we check if any other `<table1>` in `<tables1>` has similar values. eg. `<table1 ID="1" Name="a1"/>` has following values as per xml given below (1,2,3,10) obtained from `<tables3/>`

Now i need to scan complete `<tables1>` to check if any other `<table1 ID="x" Name="y"/>` has same values as for `<table1 ID="1" Name="a1"/>` (1,2,3,10).

If the values are same, i have to consider only one of the two based on priority (obtained from some more elements in `<table1>`) as per requirement specifications.

I have thought of two methods (please suggest which one to use) : Method 1. Creating a variable and using node-set

```
<xsl:variable name="xyz"><xsl:apply-templates select="//table1"/>    </xsl:variable>



<xsl:template match="table1">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()">
    </xsl:copy-of>
    <value id=""/> <!-- This value element is computed using the computations mentioned above -->
  </xsl:template>
```

Then create a node set which will contain complete `<tables1></tables1>` with associated values. After this in the routine(current) template compute values for that `<table1>` and compare with this variable node-set.

Kindly suggest if the method 1 (creating node-set and variable) is ok or not? Additionally i am getting an error in `<xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()">`

Method 2: As asked in the first question in this post. Calling template for `<table1>` inside template `<table1>`

```
<tables1>
  <table1 ID="1" Name="a1">
   <table2_ID>1</table2_ID>
  </table1>
  <table1 ID="2" Name="a2">
   <table2_ID>2</table2_ID>
  </table1>
  ...
</tables1>

<tables2>
  <table2 ID="1" Name="b1">
   <table3_IDs>
     <table3_ID>1</table3_ID>
     <table3_ID>2</table3_ID>
   </table3_IDs>
  </table2>

  <table2 ID="2" Name="b2">
    <table3_IDs>
     <table3_ID>1</table3_ID>
     <table3_ID>3</table3_ID>
    </table3_IDs>
  </table2>

  <table2 ID="3" Name="b3">
    <table3_IDs>
     <table3_ID>2</table3_ID>
     <table3_ID>3</table3_ID>
    </table3_IDs>
  </table2>
 ...
</tables2>

<tables3>
  <table3 ID="1" Name="c1">
    <Value1>1</Value1>
    <Value2>10</Value2>
  </table3>
  <table3 ID="2" Name="c2">
    <Value1>1</Value1>
    <Value2>2</Value2>
    <Value3>3</Value3>
  </table3>
  <table3 ID="3" Name="c3">
    <Value1>1</Value1>
  </table3>
</tables3>
```

Comment: are you sure it's the computation and not some circular data dependency?

Comment: First observation is that "select="table1" in the first template rule looks wrong, unless your table1 element really has children also called table1. Second observation: if it's taking a long time, then it seems reasonable to guess that has something to do with the "complex computations" that you have carefully avoided showing us.

Comment: first thing to check is to replace the calculations with something dummy and see if it still freezes, plus to also check with some other XSL processor or XSL debugging tool to step manually through the stylesheet processing (there are several ones out there, some free, other have trials)

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  In doing so, you'll likely discover on your own that it's your code, not your tool, that's at fault.  Should you complete construction of an MCVE with your problem intack, we'll happily help you understand what's wrong.

Comment: I have added MVCE and a dummy code above for understanding the problem better. I have tried using dummy values and the program runs fine. Hence i had concluded that it is the computations that are causing the freezing. The select="table1" is by mistake written wrongly.I have changed it to select="//table1". There is no circular data dependency because i am dealing with different tables.

Comment: For an MCVE, you need to provide a stylesheet and a source document than any of us can download and run; you need to tell us how it behaves for you and how you expect it to behave. Then we have a chance of telling you why it behaves as it does. And by the way, we don't care a damn about your company policies. If you want us to be helpful, we expect the same from you.